# How to close an infopath form in C# style?

Tags: development, infopath

I tried XDocument.View.Window.Close(true); but it tells me "The name 'XDocument' does not exist in the current context"

I even tried thisXDocument.View.Window.Close(true); but still same error.

What other way I can close an Infopath 2010 form using code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i solved this issue

1. Added a New button and made the Action to be Submit and configured advanced area.
2. Picked Code based and Copy all my c# code to FormEvents_Submit method
3. Also added e.CancelableArgs.Cancel = false;

Everything is good with this setup.

Answer (score 1):

Moving my answer from [closed dupe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/close-infopath-form-with-managed-code/42475#42475)

From client-side managed code, which is no more than add-on:

> Application.Quit();

and

> this.Close();

are available and work in **Infopath Filler Form**.

It is not available in **Web Browser Form** (because it is run through remote Sharepoint Server 2010's **Infopath Forms Services**).

[Here are possible workarounds](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/7052/25747.aspx):

- setting a bogys submit with a close on submit, calling Submit() from code
- embedding Infopath form Web Part in ASPX page, closing it from its code

From server-side (external to Infopath code), y[ou should pass a reference to a XML (form) document being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127572/how-do-i-programmatically-close-an-infopath-form-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

To close it generally try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127572/how-do-i-programmatically-close-an-infopath-form-in-c

To close it in the context of a browser: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointinfopath/thread/d0ecbadb-ee93-4016-bbad-fe70eddc095e/

To get a reference to the form try using the `this` keyword...

Or try `this.Application.Quit()` to close the InfoPath application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.application.quit%28v=office.11%29

Comment: Actually, I did try all of those links you provided. NONE helped.