# close infopath form with managed code

Tags: development, infopath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close an infopath form in C# style?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42377/how-to-close-an-infopath-form-in-c-style)

I am trying to close the browser (aka where infopath form is loaded) with managed code. I tried some for variation below but getting error and unable to compile the code.

`thisXDocument.View.Window.Close()`; - Gives me "Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" if I put the code about 2 curly bracket at end end.

if i put the above code just before }); then i get following error.

"'XDocument' does not exist in the current context "

Same things happens with following alternatives

```
XDocument.View.Window.Close();

Application.Quit()
```

Comment: just fyi: this.application.quit or application.quit dont even show up. see this print shot. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AHcBM.png

Answer (score 1):

From client-side managed code, which is no more than add-on:

> Application.Quit();

and

> this.Close();

are available and work in **Infopath Filler Form**.

It is not available in **Web Browser Form** (because it is run through remote Sharepoint Server 2010's **Infopath Forms Services**).

[Possible workarounds](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/7052/25747.aspx)

From server-side (external to Infopath code), y[ou should pass a reference to a XML (form) document being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127572/how-do-i-programmatically-close-an-infopath-form-in-c)